# Online transitive closure better than O(N^2) per edge addition

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, ds.data-structures, transitive-closure

I'm looking for an online algorithm to maintain the transitive closure of a directed acyclic graph with a time complexity less than O(N^2) per edge addition. My current algorithm is like this:

```
For every new edge u->v connect all nodes in Pred(u) \cup { u } with all nodes in Succ(v) \ \cup { v }.
```

For O(N^2) edges this translates in a total time complexity of O(N^4) which much worse than, for example, [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O(n) time per edge addition:

- G. F. Italiano (1986): [Amortized efficiency of a path retrieval data structure](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975%2886%2990098-8), *Theoretical Computer Science* 48, 273–281.
- J. A. La Poutré and J. van Leeuwen (1988): [Maintenance of transitive closures and transitive reductions of graphs](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-19422-3_9), *Proc. WG 1987*.

Comment: See also: D. M. Yellin. Speeding up dynamic transitive closure for bounded degree graphs. Acta Informatica, 30:369–384, 1993.

Comment: First paper provides two important operations from transitive closure, but I need a third one: iterating through all accessible nodes. The second paper is good, though.

Comment: @Alexandru The first paper provides a nxn table which lets you determine if one node is reachable from another in constant time. So to iterate over all nodes reachable from a given node, just iterate that column and see which pointers are non-null. Or you could just iterate the descendant tree, which is O(k) where k is the number of reachable nodes.

Comment: Italiano algorithm is really good. Super fast, easy to understand and implement.